# Powershell API key in header

Tags: rest, api, powershell

I have an API authorization key that i need to parse into the -headers section of a rest API call.  The format of the API key needs to be

```
{"Authorization":"<API Key here>"}
```

At the moment I have the raw key, so I am trying to put it into that format by:

```
$tokenheader = @{"Authorization"=$token}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -URI $testURI -Headers $tokenheader -ContentType 'application/json' -Verbose
```

I then echo $tokenheader to debug:

```
"real token: " + $tokenheader
```

This results:

```
real token: System.Collections.Hashtable
```

What is making it return that and not {"Authorization":"blah"}?

Comment: The `Hashtable` type doesn't override [the `ToString()` method inherited from `System.Object`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,52) so you get the name of the objects type back. Did you intend to do `"real token: " + $tokenheader['Authorization']`?

Comment: yes!  So that should return the content of the Authorization parameter as configured in the Header, yes?

Comment: Yes, that is correct :-)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!